# Pi Glow programming on python

Tags: python

After following the steps on [this page](https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow). I did everything correctly and when I try to run the test.py file it says this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "test.py" , line 9, in <module>
      piglow = PiGlow()
    File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in _init_
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times and i pressed ls and it finds the file

Comment: Try tweeting Jason - https://twitter.com/boeeerb

Comment: The error message is quite clear. The file `/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py` doesn't exists. Seems like you downloaded the file `piglow.py` to the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, it's saying that `/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py` isn't a valid file or directory. You must not have created the file in the correct location or you didn't create it at all. Try checking your Downloads folder and see if it is in there.

Comment: Alternatively, the file is there with incorrect permissions.

Comment: I would have added that but in their case it seems that this is their home directory, meaning that they should have permissions to modify any file existing in the `/pi` folder. So unless they messed up their own permissions (which I can highly doubt), this file should be completely accessible. @Jacobm001

Comment: If this was U&L I'd agree with you, but we get a ton of people that have no idea what permissions are, or really anything else linux related. It wouldn't surprise me if the user downloaded the file with `sudo wget`, which would screw up permissions. +1 from me either way, though!